# ¿ Como leer un archivo línea por línea de forma sincrónica Node.js?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Leer un csv línea por línea, realizar una operación que consume tiempo en cada línea e ir a la siguiente línea.

Alguna sugerencia sobre como podría hacerlo, Agradezco de antemano sus respuestas

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar con async/await de la siguiente forma:

```
let myFunction = async () => {
    console.log('resolviendo...')
    let result = await resolve5seg()
    console.log(result)
    console.log('resuelto :)')
}

let resolve5seg = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('5 seg despues');
    }, 5000);
  });
}


myFunction()
```

[Codigo - CodePen](https://codepen.io/leyvalt/pen/VERMKK?editors=1111)

Cada que pongas `await` antes de una instrucción el programa se va a esperar hasta ejecutar esa linea para poder pasar a la siguiente.

Debes de tener en cuenta que el  **async/await** funciona como una promesi.

[Más información sobre Async/Await](https://medium.com/@jmz12/callbacks-promesas-y-async-await-que-alguien-me-explique-514137cb57e2)